# Share cookies between ASP.NET MVC project and Web API project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have got one solution with 2 projects. One is an ASP.NET MVC web application and the other is a Web API project. What i want to do is share cookies between the 2 applications. When deployed on the server the first application is hosted on **mydomain.com** and the other at **api.mydomain.com** (sub-domain). I also use https. I use ASP.NET Identity in the MVC project as an authentication system. After reading numerous articles on the internet i have done the following:

1) In web.config file, in both projects, have included the following machine key tag.

```
<machineKey validationKey="3DF5D185FFB897592E14ED51A6DDC3E2729827A2F2180151A1BC39BE5C035D15F23700C928EFDBACEAEE498D05B76C65537FDEFB673039BCD961045C3BA8ACD3" 
            decryptionKey="CE274BA1DB61C086A80F5D8BD1AC5AC92A8BA19F37E04FC7" validation="SHA1" />
```

2) In the MVC project i have configured the the ASP.NET Identity Cookie in the following way:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/index"),
      Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
      {  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
      },
      SlidingExpiration = true,
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45),
      CookieName = "MyCookie",
      CookieDomain = ".mydomain.com"
 });
```

3) In the Web API project i have enabled and configured CORS and i have added the following configuration in the web.config (CORS is working fine in the production enviroment):

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"></add>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="mydomain.com" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

4) I have added the httpCookies section (in both projects) as follows:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" domain=".mydomain.com" httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

In my Web API controllers i have applied the **Authorize** attribute as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
   //My action methods here
}
```

Finally from the MVC project i try to call my service using an jQuery Ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
   url: viewModelParameters.myUrl,
   type: "get",
   dataType: "json",
   data: { userId: viewModelParameters.id },
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   },
   crossDomain: true,
   statusCode: {
      200: function (user) {
      }
   }
});
```

I receive the following message:

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

In the request headers i can see that the cookie is included in the request. Could you please suggest a solution or think about what am i missing out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you commented out the `SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication` in your WebApiConfig?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't have the answer to your question, but I wanted to say that your cookies are not secure any more after you posted the secret keys in your question.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the `app.UseCookieAuthentication()` in both the WebAPI and MVC projects.